# How to extract words combination of a string from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a string like this:

```
my_string = "Hello, I need to find php, software-engineering, html, security and safety things or even Oracle in your dataset. #C should be another opetion, databases and queries"
```

and a list like this:

```
my_list = ['C#', 'Django' 'Software-Engineering', 'C', 'PHP', 'Oracle Cload', 'React', 'Flask', 'IT-Security market', 'Databases and Queries']
```

I want to extract each possible my_string' words from my_list.

This is what I expect:

```
['PHP', 'Software-Engineering', 'C', 'Oracle Cload', 'IT-Security market', 'Databases and Queries']
```

This is what I tried:

```
import re
try:
    user_inps = re.findall(r'\w+', my_string)
    extracted_inputs = set()
    for user_inp in user_inps:
        if user_inp.lower() in set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), my_list)):
            extracted_inputs.add(user_inp)
except Exception:
    extracted_inputs = set()
```

But I get this:

```
['php', 'C']
```

Efficiency is also a concern to me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is the match supposed to be case sensitive?

Comment: No, it does not matter. Not too huge. A list with some thousand elements (which probably does not consider huge)

Comment: And when you say efficiency, what performance stats are we looking at? Do we have a huge input string and a huge array to match?

Comment: I just edited my answer

Comment: In your expected output, you have included words which are not an element in your list. However they are within an element in your list, such as `Oracle Cloud`. Are you wanting to match any value where part of the element in your list matches?

Comment: @PacketLoss Yes I want any possible keyword in my string be found in my_list elements and be suggested as an output list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do most of this w/ pure Python, if you want to avoid `re`.  This will be *plenty* fast for lists on the order of thousands of words.

Basic plan: clean up the punctuation, tokenize everything, use sets for matching.  For small app, you could tinker with the tokens in keywords to omit things like finding the "and".

```
my_string = "Hello, I need to find php, software-engineering, html, security and safety things or even Oracle in your dataset. #C should be another opetion, databases and queries"
my_list = ['C#', 'Django', 'Software-Engineering', 'C', 'PHP', 'Oracle Cload', 'React', 'Flask', 'IT-Security market', 'Databases and Queries']

# make table of tokens : phrases
keywords = {}
for word in my_list:
    # split each word into tokens
    tokens = {w.lower() for w in word.replace('-',' ').split()}
    for t in tokens:
        keywords[t] = word


# tokenize the string my_string
# note:  this is specifically tailored to your input with commas and hyphens, you may need to
#        make this more universal
my_string_tokens = {t.lower() for t in my_string.replace(',','').replace('-',' ').split()}

# now you can just intersect the sets, which is much more efficient than nested looping
matches = my_string_tokens & set(keywords.keys())

for match in matches:  # do what you want here...
    print(f'token: {match:20s}->  {keywords[match]}')
```

Produces:

```
token: queries             ->  Databases and Queries
token: php                 ->  PHP
token: oracle              ->  Oracle Cload
token: engineering         ->  Software-Engineering
token: databases           ->  Databases and Queries
token: software            ->  Software-Engineering
token: and                 ->  Databases and Queries
token: security            ->  IT-Security market
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution needs to be efficient and we're looking at a few thousands to start with, I'd suggest you go with a `Bloom Filter` implementation.

#### TL;DR

A Bloom filter is a data structure designed to tell you, rapidly and memory-efficiently, whether an element is present in a set. [Read More or try out here](https://llimllib.github.io/bloomfilter-tutorial/).

#### Code:

```
from bloom_filter import BloomFilter  # pip install bloom-filter
from nltk.util import ngrams
import re


def clean(s):
    s = s.replace(",", " ").replace("-", " ").replace(".", " ").lower()
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)


def clean_wo_space(s):
    s = s.replace(",", " ").replace("-", " ").replace(".", " ").lower()
    return re.sub(r'\s+', '', s)


def _initialize_bloom(phrases: list):
    bloom = BloomFilter(max_elements=1000, error_rate=0.1)
    for phrase in phrases:
        bloom.add(clean_wo_space(phrase))
    return bloom


def main():
    phrases_repo = ['C#', 'Django', 'Software-Engineering', 'C', 'PHP', 'Oracle Cloud', 'React', 'Flask',
                    'IT-Security market', 'Databases and Queries']

    input_string = "Hello, I need to find php, software-engineering, html, security and safety things or even Oracle in your dataset. C# should be another opetion, databases and queries"

    initialized_bloom = _initialize_bloom(phrases_repo)

    n_grams = set([' '.join(gram) for n in range(1, 4)
                   for gram in ngrams(clean(input_string).split(), n)])

    matches = [i for i in n_grams if clean_wo_space(i) in initialized_bloom]

    print(matches) # output ['c#', 'databases and queries', 'php', 'software engineering']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

#### The Approach:

- On application start Iterate on your `to_match` keywords repository array and parse it through a normalization method lower cases the words, removes special characters and so on.
- Train a `bloom filter` object that would store your `normalized_to_match` into a hash.
- Now that you have your `bloom filter` ready, you take your input string and parse it through the same normalizer method (so that both strings are of the same format and normalized)
- Convert your normalized input into `n-grams` where n is the largest word count of the phrase you want to match.

  `to_match = ["hello", "world", "Foo Bar", "Hey there it's me"] # n would be 4`
- The above step would give you all possible sequential word combinations that can exist.
- Now simply iterate on your `n_grams_array` to check with the `bloom filter` for existence. If it returns `true` then it means that the word exists.

#### Advantages of the approach:

- Bloom filters are extremely fast lookups. Especially for large datasets.
- Flexibility to get fuzziness (well not really) but you can configure the confidence of the match to low to get fuzzy matches (or false positives)

Answer (score 0):

We can split up the keywords in your list, and search for each element within your `string.lower()`. Given there are hypens, we also need to check and split for hypens.

I have also made the assumption that you forget to add a `,` in your list after Django.

```
my_string = "Hello, I need to find php, software-engineering, html, security and safety things or even Oracle in your dataset. #C should be another opetion, databases and queries"
my_list = ['C#', 'Django', 'Software-Engineering', 'C', 'PHP', 'Oracle Cload', 'React', 'Flask', 'IT-Security market', 'Databases and Queries']

result =[]

for idx, keyword in enumerate(my_list):
    if '-' in keyword:
        keyword = keyword.split('-')
    else:
        keyword = keyword.split()
    for word in keyword:
        if word.lower() in my_string.lower() and my_list[idx] not in result and len(word) > 1:
            result.append(my_list[idx])


result
['Software-Engineering', 'C', 'PHP', 'Oracle Cload', 'IT-Security market', 'Databases and Queries']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I found a bug as my first try. For example if you add **me** to string and **'T-Shirts & Merchandise'** in the list, then **'T-Shirts & Merchandise'** will be return as an output but shouldn't as me is not equal with  **Merchandise **

Comment: You can resolve this by adding 'and if len(word) > 1' as we do not want to be searching single letters. I have updated the code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

my_string = """
  Hello, I need to find php, software-engineering,
  html, security and safety things or even Oracle in your
  dataset. #C should be another opetion, databases and queries
"""

my_list = [
  'C#', 'Django', 'Software-Engineering',
  'C', 'PHP', 'Oracle Cload', 'React',
  'Flask', 'IT-Security market',
  'Databases and Queries'
]

result = set()

for list_item in my_list:
  if re.search(list_item, my_string, re.IGNORECASE):
    result.add(list_item)

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider cleaning your `my_list` since it has common words like "and", "IT" and at the same time it has multiple keywords in one place like "Database and Queries"

The problem with your code is that It looks for an exact match in "my_list". You will need to iterate through every sub-string in your my_list if you want to find "matching" words.

```
extracted_inputs = set()

for list_keyword in my_list:
  keywords = list_keyword.replace("-", " ")
  for item in keywords.split():
    if re.search(item, my_string, re.IGNORECASE):
      extracted_inputs.add(list_keyword)
      break
```

result:

```
{'C', 'IT-Security market', 'PHP', 'Software-Engineering', 'Databases and Queries', 'Oracle Cload'}
```